# System.Collection.Generic.RandomizedStringEqualityComparer is not a GenericTypeDefinition."

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I am  Getting "System.Collection.Generic.RandomizedStringEqualityComparer is not a GenericTypeDefinition.MakeGenericType may not be called on a type for which Type.IsGenericTypeDefinition is true."
error while creating Visual C++ Win32 Console Application.
[image]

This is the ScreenShot of that error.

Answer (score 5):

Rather than completely uninstalling, a better solution for this is to clear off the Component Model Cache in %USER_PATH%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\ComponentModelCache.

After deleting the cache folder, just relaunch Visual Studio 2012 once again, and build your project.

Worked for me.

Comment: Thanks. I faced with similar problem and you solution helped

Answer (score 0):

I saw this problem too.
What helped me was that I uninstalled Visual Studio 2012 and then installed it again... In my solution files there were C# and C++ projects and only the C++ project gave that error above (again - it was resolved when I re-installed VS2012).

Answer (score 0):

This will happened to me also.. when i cleared Temp files in windows.. simply reinstall the product and make sure.. it will not happened next time..
i already have vs 2015 so simply updated IDE it will automatically install require files....

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the \AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\ComponentModelCache folder as suggested and restarting VS2012 worked for me.